# Convert thumbnail ID into image URL

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have a site that needs to migrate from WP E-Commerce to WooCommerce.

I'm trying to use `WP All Import Pro` + `WP All Import Woocommerce add on` to do this.

I exported the WP E-Commerce products in an XML file, and imported the XML file into WooCommerce products using WP All Import.

It works fine, except I can't get the image URL from the XML file, there is only a thumbnail ID, which can't be used by the WP All Import Woocommerce add on (that I can see).

So, **I'd love to be able to convert a list of thumbnail IDs into their image URL equivalents**, and then swap these these URLs into the thumbnail ID field in the XML file.

How do I do this? Help appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the original image, or one of the resized versions (thumbnail, large, etc)?

Comment: Have you tried using other plugin to export? Can I get to see your xml file ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two functions you can use for this: `wp_get_attachment_url` to get the full sized image or `wp_get_attachment_thumb_url`, which gets the url of the thumbnail of that attachment.  Either function takes the attachment id as the sole argument:

```
$attachment_id= 25;
//Get the full url
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
//get the thumbnail
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment_id );
```

Not sure how to get this done in your XML file, though, so this is a partial answer, but hopefully it sends you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Manny. Thanks for your answer. I am not a developer, but a designer. How could I run a PHP page to take all the thumbnail IDs, and spit out the full sized image URL, one per line? Thanks!

Comment: @steve When it runs the import there are actions you can listen for. When an action is triggered you can run a function to maniplate the data. http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/developers/action-reference/ If that's out of scope, I'd just contact support. That's not a cheap plugin and I doubt you're the first to run into this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will probably solve your problem

```
<?php if ( $post->post_type == 'data-design' && $post->post_status == 'publish' ) {
    $attachments = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
    ) );

    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            $class = "post-attachment mime-" . sanitize_title( $attachment->post_mime_type );
            $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail-size', true );
            echo '<li class="' . $class . ' data-design-thumbnail">' . $thumbimg . '</li>';
        }

    }
}
?>
```

In the post type you could specify the required post type for which you need to fetch the images.

[source](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-get-all-post-attachments-in-wordpress-except-for-featured-image/)